# Flutter: how to change label style color when it is selected

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to when a tab is selected change out color to blue and when it is not selected change the color to grey
i already did this

```
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  labelStyle: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 14.0,
  fontFamily: 'fontfamily',
  color: Colors.blue),
  unselectedLabelStyle:
  TextStyle(
  fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'fontfamily'),
  tabs: myTabs,
  controller: _tabController,
            ),
```

Comment: remove the color from label style use code below in ans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
labelColor: Colors.blue,
unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify the Text color in the labelStyle

```
  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey, //for unselected label//
  indicatorColor: Colors.grey, //indicates the label color when you click it//
  labelColor: Colors.blue, // shows the label color //
```